# IPOJO logging warning when shutting down

Tags: java, dependency-injection, apache-felix, ipojo

When the application is shutting down and some @Requires services are shutdown, ipojo is logging an exception
"The dependency is not optional, however no service object can be injected in A"

```
public class Main {

   @Requires(id = "A", proxy = false)
   private A aService

   @Bind(id = "A")
   public void bindA(A a) {
       aService = a;
   }

   @Unbind(id = "A")
   public void unbindA() {
       aService = null;
   }
 }

 @Instantiate
 @Component(imediate = true)
 @Provides(specifications = {A.class})
 public class AImpl implements A {

 }
```

I suspect (i cannot reproduce the problem on my machine) it might have something to do with proxy = false and/or setting it to null in unbind.

Answer (score 0):

This is warning telling you that at that time, iPOJO can't find any provider for your requirement despite the dependency is not optional.

What does that mean in practice: your unbind callback using your service may require 'null' check (in other word != null) before using the service.